# Getting video dimensions, frame rate, and length of a .webm file

Tags: java, webm

I allow users of my website to upload a .webm file.   I'd like to be able to verify that the video's dimensions, frame rate and length meet my criteria.   Is there a java or javascript API that I could use to determine these parameters?   Or does anyone know of a windows, OSx, linux, or cloud based tool that will tell me that info?

Comment: I think ffmpeg could do this.